# Magnifying a portion of Image?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can i zoom a portion of image without having to use two images. I mean, suppose you have only one image which is not big enough. I want to magnify a  portion of this image(beyond 100%) on mouse hover. I do not care if it leads to pixelation (which it of course will). 
I tried http://zoomy.me/home but it too uses two different images (small and bigger version of image).

Comment: You are tagging with `C#` and `javascript` / `jquery`. Which language must take care of the zoom? Or is the language for the solution irrelevant?

Comment: @MikedeKlerk I am working on asp.net c# . I ok with solutions in any of the three languages c#,js or JQuery.

Comment: If you only have one image you could just refer to the same file as both the low-res and the "high-res" for many of these image zooming libraries.

Comment: I did that but then it does not zoom, how they work is that when you hover over a portion of image they replace some portion of smaller image with larger one but since both are same images of same size nothing happens.

Answer (score 2):

I'd recommend using cloud zoom. We used it and it was fairly effortless:

http://www.starplugins.com/cloudzoom

Comment: I am looking for a free solution :(

Comment: It's commercial though!

Answer (score 1):

Follow these steps:

- replace the image with a canvas rendering the image
- use getImageData() to get the pixels of the rectangle around the mouse pointer
- create new magnified image data
- use putImageData() to render the magnified data in another canvas

I just scribbled an example here: http://kirox.de/test/magnify.html

Comment: I think your approach might work for me but can you please also give a little bit more details on getImageData()? How am i supposed to get the pixels of the rectangle around the mouse pointer?

Comment: Did you have a look at the example code? It is all in the onmousemove handler. With your mouse x and y (relative to the image) you can copy a 20x20 rectangle with ctx.getImageData(x-10,y-10,20,20). A documentation of the methods you can find here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D#getImageData()